# How to add new rows of values for a distinct column value in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like

```
 ORDER    STATUS   DATE
23412      200      7-2-2020
23412      300      8-2-2020
23412      400      10-2-2020
91234      300      8-2-2020
91234      400      9-2-2020
671234     200      10-3-2020
```

I want add static row for each distinct `order` with  status =600 and `date =31-12-9999`

**Expected output**

```
ORDER    STATUS   DATE
23412      200      7-2-2020
23412      300      8-2-2020
23412      400      10-2-2020
23412      600      31-12-9999
91234      300      8-2-2020
91234      400      9-2-2020
91234      600      31-12-9999
671234     200      10-3-2020
671234    600      31-12-9999
```

How can this be done in pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new `DataFrame`, add to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), sort index values by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with only stable algo `mergesort` and last convert index to default `RangeIndex` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('ORDER', keep='last').assign(STATUS=600, DATE='31-12-9999')
df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    ORDER  STATUS        DATE
0   23412     200    7-2-2020
1   23412     300    8-2-2020
2   23412     400   10-2-2020
3   23412     600  31-12-9999
4   91234     300    8-2-2020
5   91234     400    9-2-2020
6   91234     600  31-12-9999
7  671234     200   10-3-2020
8  671234     600  31-12-9999
```

There is more solutions, each is different - @Quang Hoang sorting data (maybe problem, maybe not), @sammywemmy and my solution not sorting data. Also `groupby` is obviously slow, so if performance is important better is avoid (if possible):

```
#some sample data, 100krows, 10k groups
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
L = ['7-2-2020', '8-2-2020', '10-2-2020', '8-2-2020', '9-2-2020', '10-3-2020']

df = pd.DataFrame({'ORDER': np.random.randint(10000, size=N),
                   'STATUS': np.random.randint(500, size=N),
                   'DATE':np.random.choice(L, N)}).sort_values('ORDER').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [391]: %timeit pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':df.ORDER.unique(), 'STATUS':600,'DATE':'31-12-9999'})],ignore_index=True).sort_values(['ORDER','STATUS'])
47.9 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [392]: %timeit pd.concat([df, df.drop_duplicates('ORDER', keep='last').assign(STATUS=600, DATE='31-12-9999')]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
34.1 ms ± 543 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [393]: %timeit pd.concat([group.append({'ORDER':name,'STATUS':600, 'DATE':'31-12-9999'}, ignore_index=True)  for name,group in df.groupby('ORDER')],ignore_index=True )
24 s ± 455 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
#some sample data, 100krows, 100 groups
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
L = ['7-2-2020', '8-2-2020', '10-2-2020', '8-2-2020', '9-2-2020', '10-3-2020']

df = pd.DataFrame({'ORDER': np.random.randint(100, size=N),
                   'STATUS': np.random.randint(500, size=N),
                   'DATE':np.random.choice(L, N)}).sort_values('ORDER').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [398]: %timeit pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':df.ORDER.unique(), 'STATUS':600,'DATE':'31-12-9999'})],ignore_index=True).sort_values(['ORDER','STATUS'])
31 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [399]: %timeit pd.concat([df, df.drop_duplicates('ORDER', keep='last').assign(STATUS=600, DATE='31-12-9999')]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
28 ms ± 354 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [400]: %timeit pd.concat([group.append({'ORDER':name,'STATUS':600, 'DATE':'31-12-9999'}, ignore_index=True)  for name,group in df.groupby('ORDER')],ignore_index=True )
290 ms ± 46.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to jezrael's answer, but using `pd.Series.unique()` and `sort_values`:

```
(pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':df.ORDER.unique(), 
                             'STATUS':600,
                             'DATE':'31-12-9999'})],
          ignore_index=True)
  .sort_values(['ORDER','STATUS'])
)
```

Output:

```
    ORDER  STATUS        DATE
0   23412     200    7-2-2020
1   23412     300    8-2-2020
2   23412     400   10-2-2020
6   23412     600  31-12-9999
3   91234     300    8-2-2020
4   91234     400    9-2-2020
7   91234     600  31-12-9999
5  671234     200   10-3-2020
8  671234     600  31-12-9999
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to [iterate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) through the groups, [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) the name of each grouping, and [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
pd.concat([group.append({'ORDER':name,
                         'STATUS':600,
                         'DATE':'31-12-9999'},
                ignore_index=True) 
           for name,group in df.groupby('ORDER')],
          ignore_index=True
          )


    ORDER   STATUS  DATE
0   23412   200     7-2-2020
1   23412   300     8-2-2020
2   23412   400     10-2-2020
3   23412   600     31-12-9999
4   91234   300     8-2-2020
5   91234   400     9-2-2020
6   91234   600     31-12-9999
7   671234  200     10-3-2020
8   671234  600     31-12-9999
```